# Javascript function overwriting itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry the title isn't very clear, I'm not really sure what the problem is. I'll happily rename it if anyone has a better idea.

I have a bunch of boxes with classes 'something-box' that are called up by clicking various things which I have given classes of 'something-button'. All the boxes also have a class of 'modal-box' and all are contained within a partially transparent div that comes up to cover rest of the screen ('modal-blackout'). Rather than write exactly the same code out for each one (which I was doing) I decided to make a function to attach the relevant click handlers to each button (and various other things that accompany it). I have the following js code:

```
    function modal(selector) {
        button = $(selector+'-button');
        box = $(selector+'-box');
        button.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.modal-box').hide();
            $(document).off('.hideDoc');
            $('.modal-blackout').show();
            box.show();
            $(document).on('click.hideDoc', function(e) {

                if (!box.is(e.target) && box.has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                    $('.modal-blackout').hide();
                    box.hide();
                    $(selector + '-box .error-message').html('');
                    $(document).off('.hideDoc');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    modal('.password-reset');
    modal('.login');
    modal('.signup');
```

But now every button brings up the .signup-box (or whichever one is called last). Note that if I remove the function and just write it out three times manually with the different selectors everywhere in the code, it works as I intended.

Suspect there is something fundamental I don't understand here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: can you give us a demo fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating global variables that are being overridden each time `modal()` is called. This results in `box` always referring to the box selected with the last selector, and similar for `button`.

For `button`, it's not really a problem, since you only use it once. However, the reference to `box` has to stay accurate, because it's used in the `click` event handler.

Replace:

```
function modal(selector) {
    button = $(selector+'-button');
    box = $(selector+'-box');
```

With:

```
function modal(selector) {
    var button = $(selector+'-button');
    var box = $(selector+'-box');
```

This will result in those variables being created in `modal`'s scope, so subsequent calls to `modal` can't override the variables set for previous selectors.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you don't have the var keyword in front of `box`, meaning it's either a global variable, or belongs to an outer scope.

The event handlers get a reference to this box via a closure, so when the next call of the function redefines `box`, all of them will act on the current value of box.

The easiest solution is making box local to the function by declaring and assigning it as

```
var box = ...
```

If box is defined in an outer function, and you didn't redeclare it intentionally - well, you're doing it wrong. Since you're re-assigning the value of it, I don't see the point of declaring it outside of `modal`.